# Executing Bash Script Returns Null In Java

Tags: java, linux, swing, bash, ubuntu

I'm using UBUNTU/LINUX 
I'm trying to build swing application for myself(this app need to work other platforms too) and i can not execute some commands on java.
I tried to execute "java -version"
Here is my code:

```
 Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();

    Process p = run.exec("java -version");

    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()))) {

        for (String output = br.readLine(); output != null; output = br.readLine()) {
            System.out.println(output);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

**It returns blank page no output!**

However i can execute run.exec("ls") / or ("gedit") and so on... and I GET DATA
Also i can execute internal programs that in my computer.

Why i cant execute .sh files or built-in java commands and getting blank page?

Comment: I put 2 questions in one and I made 2 answers and none are accepted :-/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `jvm` itself directs output to the error stream

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()))) {
```

Answer (score 7):

You should use `ProcessBuilder` to mix standard and error outputs:

```
    ProcessBuilder run = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-version");
    run.redirectErrorStream(true);

    Process p = run.start();

    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()))) {

        for (String output = br.readLine(); output != null; output = br.readLine()) {
            System.out.println(output);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

Check that `java` parent directory is in your `PATH` variable (output `System.getenv("PATH")`) or use a full path to the binary.

For script, use `/bin/sh` like that `ProcessBuilder run = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/sh", "/path/to/your/script");`

All path can be `absolute` starting with `/`, or relative (without `/`) to `System.getProperty("user.dir")`.